# Pandas: Groupby, concatenate one column and identify the row with maximums

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datframe like this:

```
prefix  input_text target_text score
X       V           A           1
X       V           B           2
X       W           C           1
X       W           B           3
```

I want to group them by some columns and concatenate the column `target_text`, meanwhile get the maximum of `score` in each group and identify the `target_text` with highest score, like this:

```
prefix  input_text target_text score  top
X       V           A, B        2     B
X       W           C, B        3     B
```

This is my code which does the concatenation, however I just don't know about the rest.

```
df['target_text'] = df[['prefix', 'target_text','input_text']].groupby(['input_text','prefix'])['target_text'].transform(lambda x: '<br />'.join(x))
        
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['prefix','input_text','target_text'])
```

In concatenation I use html code to concat them, if I could bold the target with highest score, then it would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try

```
df.sort_values('score',ascending=False).\
  drop_duplicates(['prefix','input_text']).\
    rename(columns={'target_text':'top'}).\
      merge(df.groupby(['prefix','input_text'],as_index=False)['target_text'].agg(','.join))
Out[259]: 
  prefix input_text top  score target_text
0      X          W   B      3         C,B
1      X          V   B      2         A,B
```

Answer (score 4):

[`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) would be useful here:

```
new_df = (
    df.groupby(['prefix', 'input_text'], as_index=False).agg(
        target_text=('target_text', ', '.join),
        score=('score', 'max'),
        top=('score', 'idxmax')
    )
)
new_df['top'] = df.loc[new_df['top'], 'target_text'].values
```

`new_df`:

```
  prefix input_text target_text  score top
0      X          V        A, B      2   B
1      X          W        C, B      3   B
```

Aggregations are as follows:

1. `target_text` is joined together using `', '.join`.
2. `score` is aggregated to only keep the max value with `'max'
3. `top` is the `idxmax` of the `score` column.

```
new_df = (
    df.groupby(['prefix', 'input_text'], as_index=False).agg(
        target_text=('target_text', ', '.join),
        score=('score', 'max'),
        top=('score', 'idxmax')
    )
)
```

```
  prefix input_text target_text  score  top
0      X          V        A, B      2    1
1      X          W        C, B      3    3
```

The values in `top` are the corresponding indexes from `df`:

```
  prefix input_text target_text  score
0      X          V           A      1
1      X          V           B      2  # index 1
2      X          W           C      1
3      X          W           B      3  # index 3
```

These values need to be "looked up" from `df`:

```
df.loc[new_df['top'], 'target_text']
```

```
1    B
3    B
Name: target_text, dtype: object
```

And assigned back to `new_df`. [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) is needed to break the index alignment.

Answer (score 3):

try via `sort_values()`, `groupby()` and `agg()`:

```
out=(df.sort_values('score')
       .groupby(['prefix', 'input_text'], as_index=False)
       .agg(target_text=('target_text', ', '.join), score=('score', 'max'), top=('target_text', 'last')))
```

output of `out`:

```
    input_text  prefix  score   target_text     top
0       V       X       2           A, B         B
1       W       X       3           C, B         B
```

**Explaination:**

we are sorting values of 'score' and then grouping by column 'input_text' and 'prefix' and aggregrating values that are as follows:

- we are joining together the values of 'target_text' by `', '`
- we are getting only max value of 'score column' bcz we are aggregrating `max`
- we are getting last value of 'target_text' column since we sorted previously so now we are aggregrating `last` on it

**Update:**

If you have many more columns to include then you can aggregrate them if they are not in high in number otherwise:

```
newdf=df.sort_values('score',ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['prefix','input_text'],ignore_index=True)
#Finally join them    
out=out.join(newdf[list of column names that you want])
#For example:
#out=out.join(newdf[['target_first','target_last]])
```

Comment: @HenryEcker good suggestion...Thanks I previously tried this but it is not working because I passed `sort=False`  **:)**

Comment: Thanks, however, one thing was ignored that is in Beny's answer. I didn't say that my columns are limited to those. I have other columns too. The Beny's answer, as I tried, keep them, but yours don't.

Comment: @Ahmad updated answer....Kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: Thank you very much! I'd like to accept your answer, however for some reasons, like being concise,  I accepted the other answer. Anyways, thanks.